# My file pathe is content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000095307 but i can not convert base64 (pdf,doc,excel) in kotlin

Tags: excel, kotlin, pdf, base64, doc

How to covert to pdf, doc, excel file which choose in application in base64 string
I got this
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000095307
but i can not convert base64 (pdf,doc,excel) in kotlin
How to solved this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution here that works for me

```
1. val contentUri = Uri.parse("url here of file path")
                    val fileContent = getContentFromFileUri(applicationContext, contentUri)
                    if (fileContent != null) {
                        havwPhoto = byteArrayToBase64(fileContent)
                        // Now you have the Base64 encoded string of the file content
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case where the content couldn't be read
                    }

2.  fun getContentFromFileUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): ByteArray{
            val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
            val inputStream: InputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)
            val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int
            try {
                while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it!! } != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                }
                return outputStream.toByteArray()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                inputStream?.close()
                outputStream.close()
            }
            return null
        }

3.        fun byteArrayToBase64(byteArray: ByteArray): String {
            return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).